# Karel the Robot is empty using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have downloaded and installed the latest version of Java JDK (both version X86 and X64) [as Stanford tutorial said].
As of writing the latest version is 8u66
But still the program doesn't show up anything. I don't like eclipse and I'm pretty sure that somehow this program works on IntelliJ too. I've done the steps below:
1. File -> New -> Project from Existing Source -> Assignment1
2. paste the following code into the CollectNewspaperKarel.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    stanford.karel.Karel.main(new String[] { "code="
            + StoneMasonKarel.class.getCanonicalName() });
}
public void run() {
}
```

and clicked on run. the programs runs perfectly but nothing doesn't show up.

[IntelliJ IDEA IMAGE,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks0W6.png)

I have searched a lot, and a lot of people said we should have JRE/JDK1.6 but on Stanford website is "Before installing Eclipse, you will first need to have a copy of the latest version of the Java JRE (Java Runtime Environment) installed on your computer. Note that Java version 1.8 is the latest version of Java."

So I assume this program should work on latest version of java too not only on 1.6

OS:            Windows 10 X64 | JAVA:          jdk-8u66 (both X64 and X86) | IntelliJ IDEA: v.15.0.2

https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/software/index.html

Comment: People who have not been to Stanford (including me) are going to have no idea what Karel the Robot or Stonemason Karel mean. You've got to give us some more context here. What are the precise instructions you are working from?

Comment: I don't go to Stanford,unfortunately :( , so I have no idea, what Stonemason Karel mean, too. I am watching Mehran Sahami's Java tutorials on YouTube, and he is working with Karel the Robot. Karel the Robot is just a program written for Students to learn Java. But as you see there is a blank page after running the program, it shouldn't be empty, instead, on the screen should Karel the Robot show up.

Answer (score 0):

I am going through courses on SEE. I also had the blank Java window when I ran a java file from the Assignments download.
I was able to get them to run in JDK 1.8 using the standard Eclipse.
Here's what I did...

There is a Stanford Eclipse plug-in. I found instructions for that at https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106a/cs106a.1178/eclipse/. Under the installation instructions for Mac or Windows, whichever you use, there is a link to the Stanford plug-in.

Then go to https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106a/cs106a.1178//resources/ and download, unzip and import into Eclipse the BlankKarelProject.zip file.

Now, I don't know a lot of stuff. But when I imported that Blank one and ran that java file, I got a blank world to load. Then in that java application window, I clicked the Load World button. A file window opened up and I navigated to the file on my local disc the world named "CollectNewspaperKarel" and then I see what the world is supposed to look like for that assignment.

I notice for the imported Assignment file there is no src or lib dirs. My best guess is I can work on/edit the assignment in the respective assignment's java file then copy paste it into the BlankKarel.java file, run, see it happen in the world I selected.